# Is the navi Yeshaya or Yeshayahu?

Tags: names, grammar-dikduk, navi-prophets

Why is the Navi sometimes referred to as ישעיה and sometimes ישעיהו? Same thing with Yirmiyah and Yirmiyahu?

Comment: And many other names.

Comment: Gedalyahu vs Gedalya

Comment: Chizkiyahu vs Chizkiya

Comment: Azaryah and Uziyahu is also one that bothered me.

Comment: I believe it is something to do with the name of Hashem being in it - the longer name has a more fuller sheim Hashem and so I think nowadays the practise is to pronounce the name / call our kids in the more shorten form. It is something like that - someone feel free to correct...

Comment: Is the current US president named Joe or Joseph?